# How can I decrease the brightness of a new image by 50 units in 2D arrays of String using if statement in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, multidimensional-array, 2d

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Combining {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] imageData={{100,90,255,80,70,255,60,50},
                                     {255,10,5,255,10,5,255,255},
                                     {255,255,255,0,255,255,255,75},
                                     {255,60,30,0,30,60,255,255}};
    
    //First, we want to crop the image down to a 4x6 image, removing the right 2 columns. Declare and initialize a new 2D array of integers with 4 rows and 6 columns called `newImage`.
    int[][] newImage = new int[4][6];
    

    //Now that you have your empty image, use nested **for** loops to copy over the data from the original image to the new image, make sure not to include the cropped out columns.

for (int i = 0; i < imageData.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < imageData[i].length - 2; j++) {
        newImage[i][j] = imageData[i][j];
      }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(newImage));

    //You want to decrease the brightness of the new image by 50 units. The way this works is that for every integer in the new 2D array, we will subtract the value by 50. Remember that the value range for the pixel is 0-255, so if the result tries to go below 0, just set it equal to 0.
    


if (imageData[i][j] - 50 < 0) {
  newImage[i][j] = imageData[i][j] - 50;
  } else {
    newImage[i][j] = 0;
    }
  
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(newImage));
  }
}
```

Below is the question I have.

We want to decrease the brightness of the new image by 50 units. The way this works is that for every integer in the new 2D array, we will subtract the value by 50. Remember that the value range for the pixel is 0-255, so if the result tries to go below 0, just set it equal to 0.

Below is the hint to the question.

Remember to check if the value minus 50 is less than 0 when iterating through the elements of the new image: if(newImage[row][column]-50<0). If that condition is true, then set the element to equal 0 else subtract 50 from the element.

Below is code I have tried to solve the question.

```
//You want to decrease the brightness of the new image by 50 units. The way this works is that for every integer in the new 2D array, we will subtract the value by 50. Remember that the value range for the pixel is 0-255, so if the result tries to go below 0, just set it equal to 0.

    if(imageData[i][j] - 50 < 0) {
          newImage[i][j] = imageData[i][j] - 50;
        } else {
          newImage[i][j] = 0;
        }
   
            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(newImage));
        }
    }
```

I keep getting syntax error in the console that cannot find symbol i and j.

```
Combining.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
    if(imageData[i][j] - 50 < 0) {
                 ^
```

Comment: Please show all your code together. It isn't clear where your if statement is located relative to the first snippet of code.

Comment: @tgdavies I have provided all the code together, you can look at it together now.

Comment: The code in your if statement operates on a single pixel with the index (I,j). You need to wrap it in two nested for loops so that you can operate on each pixel. (You will also need to think about which way around your if condition is)

Answer (score 0):

for the first part of your code

the for loop can be replaced with this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.arraycopy(imageData[i], 0, newImage[i], 0, 4);
    }
```

check the api for more detail about this method [arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int))

by the way your code will work but this is just another way

now for the issue

```
Combining.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
if(imageData[i][j] - 50 < 0) {
```

i and j in the for loop are only defined inside the loop body

local variable are defined and accessible only from where they defined so for example

```
int[][] newImage = new int[4][6];

 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.arraycopy(imageData[i], 0, newImage[i], 0, 4); // only i defined here
}

\\here you can only access imageData and newImage but not i as i out of the scope

for local variable the scope determined by the { }
```

check this to get more details about [variable scop](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/)e

so either to define i and j outside the for loop like

```
int i, j = 0;
    for (; i < imageData.length; i++) {
        for (; j < imageData[i].length - 2; j++) {
            newImage[i][j] = imageData[i][j];
        }
    }
```

or do the subtraction inside the for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageData.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < imageData[i].length - 2; j++) {
            newImage[i][j] = imageData[i][j];
            if (imageData[i][j] - 50 >= 0) {
                newImage[i][j] = imageData[i][j] - 50;
            } else {
                newImage[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
```

by the way the logic with your if is not right you should check the above version

also you can do it using that

```
newImage[i][j] -= 50;
newImage[i][j] =  newImage[i][j] >= 0 ? newImage[i][j] : 0;
```